# As3: Why my URL request doesn't works?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

So I have the following code.

```
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendMessage);

function sendMessage(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var my_vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    my_vars.senderName = a;
    my_vars.senderEmail = b;
    my_vars.senderMsg = comment;

    var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/mail.php");
    my_url.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    my_url.data = my_vars;

    var my_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    my_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    my_loader.load(my_url);
}
```

This code function is to send mail.
The million dollar question, is that my as3 can sent email when the url is

```
var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/mail.php")
```

but not

```
var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("www.somewebsite.com/mail.php")
```

I need my flash to send email, eventhough the flash and the php in different server.
(PS: I can assure you that when testing, both php and fla is in the same folder on the web)

[Taken from here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contactform/2.php)

Comment: Are you using http:// in front of the URL? I can't tell if StackOverflow just edited out or not.

Comment: No I didn't. Should I?

Comment: Yeah, I would be surprised if it understood the url without it. Also, as you mentioned, both the php file and the swf need to live on the same server or you'll have to have an appropriate crossdomain.xml on the server where the php file is.

Comment: Assume that I already upload the crossdomain.xml, what additional syntax do I need to put on the as3, so it can access the php?

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional syntax. If you have the flash debug player installed you should see any crossdomain errors when you run the script if it wasn't configured correctly. I would check the browser debug window and watch the request and make sure it's called correctly and see what the response is.